# Lesser known Ubuntu desktop applications

Tags: linux, ubuntu, repository

So, this Ubuntu software center comes with 100s of applications of all types.

In this version they have disabled rating, making it hard to find how good it is.

I found gnome-shell today, that seemed awesome. There are other ones, less well known, For eg, Abiword is far better than Open Office Org Word processor in many ways. (Altho' I dont like word processors themselves.)

What are the other less well known applications that you use and like. One application per answer.

Comment: no.  we already have [Must Have Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/1430/must-have-linux-software) and [Must Have Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/4685/must-have-ubuntu-packages) and [Favorite Linux that No One's Heard About](http://superuser.com/questions/2652/whats-your-favourite-piece-of-linux-software-nobodys-heard-about) questions.  take this to a discussion forum -- this might be perfect for Ubuntu Forums, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Revelation - a better place to keep passwords than the preinstalled one. Easy to keep the passwords file anywhere you like (on a USB stick, for example) and tell Revelation where to locate it.

The concept is that you store all your passwords in one encrypted file, and when you open that file you need to type your password. But you only need to remember that single password.